# MySQL dependency error on linux

Tags: rhel, software-installation, mysql, dependencies

I have the 'mysql-community-release-el7.rpm' on RHEL 7.8.
When trying to install I believe its trying to install the RHEL 8 version hence throwing the dependency error.

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:8.0.21-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 8.0.21-1.el8 for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 8.0.11 for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
```

Error below

```
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.11)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
```

How do I force it to install el7 version instead of el8??
Please suggest.

Comment: What does `sudo yum search mysql-community-server` return?

Comment: N/S matched: mysql-community-server 
mysql-community-server-debug-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package mysql-community-server-debug
mysql-community-server-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package mysql-community-server
mysql-community-server.x86_64 : A very fast and reliable SQL database server
mysql-community-server-debug.x86_64 : The debug version of MySQL server

Comment: What's the repo you're using?

Comment: #rpm -qa | grep mysql
**mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch**

Comment: Thanks for the replies Artem. Used **wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7.rpm** to get the repo.

Comment: You have too many repos enabled and installed. Decide exactly what you want first and uninstall redundant packages.

This also might work `yum --enable-repo=mysql-cluster-7.6-community --disable-repo=mysql-cluster-8.0-community install mysql-community-server`

Comment: Ran these   #yum-config-manager --disable mysql80-community  #yum-config-manager --enable mysql-cluster-7.6-community .It was successful but installed 5.7 instead of MySQL8  # mysqladmin -V
mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib **5.7.31-ndb-7.6.15**, for Linux on x86_64

Comment: What do you see in the output of `yum repolist`?  It looks like you have the `mysql57-community` repo enabled, not the `mysql80-community` repo.

Comment: Yup true, the above process was installing mysql 5.7. There was no mysql8 for EL7 in the rpms that I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally install. Downloaded the tar file specific to RHEL7 from 'https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/' Imported each rpm form the tar and the finally yum installs 'mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el7.x86_64' successfully.